# linux shared memory fault when access an struct array in the global management struct

Tags: linux, caching, shared-memory

I have created a linux shared memory by shmget,and I create a global management struct like this on the first memory address,

```
 typedef struct{
        mini_kv_key *slots;
        unsigned int slots_mask;
        unsigned int slots_num;
        mini_cache_segment **segments;  
        unsigned int segments_num;
        unsigned int segments_mask;
    } mini_cache_globals;
```

I try to use

```
mini_cache_globals mini_cache = shmat(0, NULL, 0);
```

get this management struct,however I find that when i use

```
mini_cache->slots[index];
```

to get a mini_kv_key will return a segment fault,so does access

```
mini_cache->segments_num[index];
```

I am so sorry for my poor english,and the code is [here](https://github.com/wudikua/minicache)

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and use `gdb` (and perhaps `valgrind`) to debug.

Comment: Also, test the result of `shmat`. On failure (when its result is `(void*)-1L`) use `perror` or `strerror` to display `errno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access pointers that are valid only in other process (the process actually created structure and set pointer.) Any pointers saved in shared structure will not be valid in any other process. To achieve your aim you should save all data that need to be shared in shared memory and store relative offsets instead of pointers.